# hide the date picker whole month dates depending on selected date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide the date picker dates of the whole month depending on selected date for example if I select the date of `2018/09/23` it has to hide the whole  9th month dates. 
or if I select `2018/10/25` it has to disable whole 10th month of dates.

EDIT:I don't want to enable it back.

here is my date picker code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Can any one help me how can i do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about how to display it again once it disappeared?

Comment: No i haven't thought about that

Comment: To be honest, it's a bit unclear what you're asking for. If you'd like to restrict datepicker to a certain range, you should take a look at this page: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: NO i am not trying for restrict datepicker to a certain range, 

For example if i select date of 2018/10/23 it has to disable whole 10th month of whole dates.

Comment: then how will you enable it back?

Comment: NO i dont want to enable it back

Comment: Can you please help me out

Comment: All you need to manually disable month dates. use onSelect event of DatePicker.

Comment: @Hardik can you please explain me how can i do that

Comment: @Hardik it wont be happen on dynamically?

Comment: @suresh follow this http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

Comment: @Hardik how that useful to me